# I'm developing a game but my click event on a dynamically created div in JavaScript does not work

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm developing a platform game for which I created a `window.onload` event which gets called.

In this event I create a div element, set its ID, and then its `onclick` property. I'm absolutely positive my syntax is correct but it will not fire the alert when I click the Mario div.

```
window.onload = showChoice;

// Let the player choose a character
function showChoice() {
    var opt1 = document.createElement("div");
    opt1.setAttribute("id","opt1_mario");
    opt1.onclick = function() {
        alert("You chose Mario!");
    }
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(opt1);

    var opt2 = document.createElement("div");
    opt2.setAttribute("id","opt2_luigi");
    opt2.onclick = function() {
        alert("You chose Luigi!");
    }
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(opt2);
}
```

The actual gameplay works, but I'm being held up by a lousy click event. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You have to provide more information because the code you posted works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/WT9ug/1.

Comment: Apologies for the very late reaction. It turns out I had some z-indices set to negative integers, which caused the problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the very late reaction. It turns out I had some z-indices set to negative integers, which caused the problem. :)

When I altered my z-indices to positive ones, all was well.